# private constructor, init и companion object в Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, объекты, конструктор, retrofit2

Есть код:

```
class ApiClient private constructor() {
    
        val api: ApiInterface
            get() = retrofit!!.create(
                ApiInterface::class.java)
    
        init {
    
            retrofit =
                Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
    
        }
    
        companion object {
    
            private val BASE_URL = "http://pharmacyserver.nikolyla.beget.tech/"
    
            private var apiClient: ApiClient? = null
            private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
    
            val instance: ApiClient?
                @Synchronized get() {
    
                    if (apiClient == null) {
    
                        apiClient =
                            ApiClient()
                    }
    
                    return apiClient
                    
                }
        }
    }
```

Я не вполне понимаю, как он работает. Ввиду чего у меня есть вопросы:

1. Для чего здесь `private constructor`?
2. Почему присваивать значение переменной нужно именно в `init`, разве этого нельзя сделать без него?
   В интернете по поводу init я прочитал следующее:

This is an example of a Kotlin class having a primary constructor. But like java, if we have to perform some task in constructor how can we do that in Kotlin? Because this is not possible in the primary constructor.

Either we can use secondary constructor or we can use init block. Here, in this block, we will talk about the Init Block.

А также: Основной конструктор не может содержать в себе исполняемого кода. Инициализирующий код может быть помещён в соответствующие блоки (initializers blocks), которые помечаются словом init.

Но для чего нужен `init`, а также для чего он нужен конкретно в этом коде, я так и не понял

3. Для чего здесь нужен `companion object`?

Опять же информация об этой конструкции из интеренте:

Object expressions create objects of anonymous classes, that is, classes that aren't explicitly declared with the class declaration. Such classes are useful for one-time use. You can define them from scratch, inherit from existing classes, or implement interfaces. Instances of anonymous classes are also called anonymous objects because they are defined by an expression, not a name.

Но из текста описания я так и не понял, почему переменные создаются в `companion object`, затем оодной из них присваивается значение в init, а также почему код, который находится внутри `companion object` не может работать без `companion object`

Comment: Код похож на реализацию паттерна Одиночка. Приватный конструктор - для невозможности создать экземпляры данного класса. В "компаньоне" определено "статическое" свойство для доступа к единственному экземпляру класса.

Comment: @Crush, а для чего может понадобиться запрещать создавать экземпляры класса?

Comment: Необходимость создания только одного объекта для класса, например, для подключения к базе данных или в данном случае - инстанса Retrofit.

Comment: Singleton + Lazy initialisation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization